# Facebook comments plugin broken?

Tags: facebook-comments

How do I solve an issue where the Facebook comments plugin seems to be completely broken?  Please see the screen shot.

When I am logged in to Facebook, I see what you see there.  Where the plugin HTML is meant to be, it says "skin must be one of the following values: light, dark".

When I am logged out of Facebook, it is completely blank.  I am seeing this error on all browsers, on multiple test computers (including various configurations on browserstack.com), on every website that I can find that uses the Facebook social comments plugin - including Facebook itself!

[image: screenshot of Facebook's development page for the comments plugin]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Facebook have dramatically changed their comments plugin code.  All sites using this plugin will probably have to update their code ASAP because the old code doesn't seem to work any longer.

To get Facebook's own page working, I just had to type in "light" in the Color Scheme box.